# LinkedIn Profile Statistics

Tags: linkedin-api

Is there any possibility of obtaining the following statistics in LinkedIn Profile through the API ?

1. Posts / Publications
2. Impressions
3. Likes
4. Comments
5. Clicks
6. Share